# Give Margin to td tag either CSS nor cellspacing

Tags: css

I want space from both sides for td tag content of table.

```
table td {
  margin:4px;
}
```

Nothing works.

Comment: If any of the answers below, helped you solve your problem, please **[mark it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this adjusting the **[`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)** of your table
(provided that your table's **[`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)** is set to "separate" which is the default for tables).
E.g., add this to your CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px 2px;
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Tunaw/)**.

**Compatibility note**:
According to MDN, the above solution might not be compatible with IE 7 or older.